# Ubuntu 16.04 being very slow

Tags: 16.04

I am using a machine having 8GB of RAM and intel i7 processor. Ubuntu 16.04 is installed on my system with 7GB of swap space. But when i open a few applications concurrently, it just gets stuck.I have used ubuntu 14.04 with 32 bit in my past and it worked like charm for me. So i have came to this conclusion that my system is running slow because of the 64 bit architecture of ubuntu 16.04. Can anybody suggest me whether i am right or wrong. I am thinking of switching to 32 bit of ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You're wrong. An Intel i7 requires 64-bit. Please post other hardware specs, namely what graphics card and, if Nvidia, whether or not you installed proprietary drivers, which version and how...

Comment: @CelticWarrior 64-bit is not required for an i7. But please, no. 32-bit won't run any faster than 64-bit- in fact, it will run slower due to the 2GB RAM allocation limit. And yes, OP, please post all hardware specs and drivers.

Comment: @patrickyi - I know ;-) . The "i7 requires 64-bit" should be red as "using 32-bit with an i7 is stupid for obvious reasons", one of which you already mentioned; other is running 64-bit only software isn't possible in a 32-bit OS.

Comment: You need to test a 32bit version from Live USB, and suggest yourself which one works better. It's hard to imagine anyone will do it for you.

Comment: Using top command check which process uses most of cpu when you run a few apps.